# How do I change the add to cart text on the cart page only?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change the "add to cart" button text to 'Complete Sale' when on the shopping cart page,  be "subscribe now" on product id 4968, and be 'Book' everywhere else.

Here is my code in the functions.php file:

```
function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {


    if (is_single('Product1')) {

        return __( 'Subscribe Now', 'woocommerce' );

    } else {

        return __( 'Book', 'woocommerce' );

    }
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );
```

Comment: above code looks fine. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: Yeh for some reason Im trying to set the basket page to have the word "Complete sale" the product with Id 4968 to have the word ''Subscribe Now" and everything else to have "Book" this code shows subscribe now on the product in question Book in the basket and Book everywhere else.

Comment: maybe if statement need wrap in function - woo_coostom_cart_...() ?

Comment: Yes..... the if statement is in `woo_custom_cart_button_text` function. Isn't it?

Comment: sorry code didn't get added see revised.

Comment: It looks like you are using the single product page filter... did you try the archives one 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text'? https://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-add-to-cart-button-text/

Comment: That caused the pages to have the text 'Add to Basket''

Comment: @JoshTalk I'm sure it won't do that basing on your codes above..

Comment: @Reigel with the above code I'm getting 'subscribe now' on the chose product, but 'subscribe now' on other products and "book" on the cart page, I don't have any other conflicting functions so don't know why its not working.

Comment: Sod it I copied the proceed-to-checkout-button.php to my child theme and simply changed the text in there instead of using a function, but I used the function to change the text on the specific product and the other products so it kinda worked.

Comment: It's recommended in child themes to copy over the woocommerce components then add your functions thereafter to customise it.

Comment: This might not be a solution necessarily, but it's an idea I had... You could always target said button by the product ID and use some CSS to hide the text and add a `:before` or `:after` selector. It's more of a hack but I've used it before as a quick on-the-fly solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change is_single to is_page(). And put slug or id of the page inside the is_page().